# Can I extend icemaker line by joining two braided lines?

Tags: plumbing, water, ice-maker

I am moving fridge further from the current water source (sink). The existing line is a compression fitted copper.

I bought a 25’ braided line but it is a bit short for comfort. I am thinking of securing the end of that 25’ line to the wall behind new fridge location and attaching a short braided line to hook up to the fridge. Now that’s two more connections that would potentially fail but Would you do it the same way or would you go copper?

I have never run a cooper line but I think I am capable. Guessing I’d just have to buy copper line, proper cooper tubing cutters, nuts and brass compression rings.

Another reason I am considering copper is that the reviews on braided line are mixed to awful taste/smell of harden hose to no taste and smell, and from what I gather this could be due to the type of water treatment a water district gets. I also run a cheap clear plastic tubing as a backup for this very reason.

What is the recommended route here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> "Would you do it the same way or would you go copper?"

I would run 1/4" copper tubing from the shut-off valve at the water source all the way to the wall behind the refrigerator; that line I would then consider a permanent install. This is especially appropriate if the line runs through/behind cabinets or other semi-inaccessible areas.

At the wall behind the refrigerator I would install an inline valve (to provide a quick local shut off capability) and transition to braided stainless-steel jacketed hose.

NOTES:

- copper tubing compression fittings are pretty reliable
- any hose (braided line is just a hose...) should be used only in areas where a leak could be easily noticed and the hose easily replaced
- valves are often the weak point; do not use a "saddle valve" at the water source, and expect to replace any in-line valves, especially needle-valves.

Comment: And yes, it should be ok to use a 1/4" compression coupler to mate two braided supply lines together... but only if the connection is in an accessible location where a leak can be easily detected.

Comment: I have replaced numerous braided lines because they ruptured and were about to burst. I always replaced them with copper. I would run the copper right into the fridge. the trick to compression fittings is to really tighten them up... two adjustable wrenched needed.+1

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Thanks! The current fridge has a copper line and a LOT of slack at the back. Like probably 8 feet folded up in a high loop. If I go with a termination attached to the wall (the line will be coming through the joist space, up through a hole in the subfloor), 1) would you just let it stick out of the floor, 2) how would you terminate at the wall, and 3) what specific compression fitting/valve and strap would you use at the wall? Thanks! David

Comment: @JACK thanks for the tip. I always thought copper compressions were to be tightened by hand and then 1/2 turn. Would you do tighter than that?

Comment: @David If you google the tightening of compression fittings you find 1/2 turn, 1/2 to three quarters turn and one full turn.... I know that's a big help..... I probably go 1/2 turn and then see if it's leaking. If it is, then another 1/4 turn...

Comment: @JACK what do you think of PEX instead of copper? Reasons for/against it?

Comment: I'm old school, and old. I've use copper for 60 years but the PEX is an up and coming thing as are Sharkbite connectors. The copper would offer more protection for that long run.

Comment: If there's that much slack, @David, is there a reason you can't just gently move the existing copper line to the new fridge location?

Comment: @FreeMan, unfortunately, that slack is needed to move the fridge out of the cabinetry without kinking the tube too much. So my choices are to run a new copper, which is fine, or get a 50' Sharkbite PEX for $15.45 and do compression fittings as they are probably more time-tested vs Sharkbite fittings. Also, I think the PEX will last forever without developing pinholes (not that 1/4 icemaker line that mostly sits dormant would necessarily do that) and would be easier to feed / fewer tools needed. My only reservation is a potential taste-odor but then our fridge will have a carbon filter.

Answer (score 1):

wow,25 feet from the water source is long.Save yourself money and buy Pex Ice Maker Line by the foot at HD or Lowes.should run about $10.00 for 30' then buy the 2 Brass Compression Fittings,I say this because this is what New Appliances use,its a clear line and should be easy enough,youtube install it.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I am leaning PEX way too, something like this thd.co/2FOwL1S Would I be able to put compression fittings (assuming with nylon compression ring), Concern I have with PEX is, it possibly inhibiting the taste. I know this can be the case with plastic and braided line too, but I am not sure what PEX does to taste. Any thoughts?